# Can't set data in Httpcontext.Current.Session

Tags: c#, session, httpcontext

I'm a beginner in WebApi, trying to access a global container to hold and store data from a user, but can't figure out what and why the data can't store in session, please see my codes below:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
        }
        private bool IsWebApiRequest()
        {
            var appRelative = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath != null;
            var urlPrefix = appRelative && HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.StartsWith(WebApiConfig.UrlPrefixRelative);
            return urlPrefix;
        }
        void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Session is Available here
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
             {
                 if (HttpContext.Current.Session["con"] == null)
                 {
                     HttpContext.Current.Session["con"] = "Sample";
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route("setsession"),HttpGet]
    //api/v1/sample/setsession/
    public IHttpActionResult SetSession()
    {
        var con = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["con"];
        HttpContext.Current.Session["con"]= "Hello World";
        con = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["con"];
        return Ok();
    }

    [System.Web.Http.Route("getsession"), HttpGet]
    //api/v1/sample/getsession/
    public IHttpActionResult GetSession()
    {
        var data = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["con"];
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

SampleController.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();
        var constraintsResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintsResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("apiVersionConstraint", typeof(ApiVersionConstraint));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintsResolver);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(config));
        config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, new SecureJsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // Ignoring circular reference globally
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        // Preserving circular reference globally
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

        // Remove the JSON formatter
        //config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

        // Remove the XML formatter
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

As you can see, i set the `HttpContext.Current.Session["con"]` to its default value `Sample`, to let me know there is a value. the scenario is when i set a value from `api/v1/sample/setsession` to that `Session["con"]` the result is totally works fine, the `"Hello World"` passed to `Session["con"]`. but when i do `"api/v1/sample/getsession"`, the condition in `global.asax.cs` success and  `HttpContext.Current.Session["con"] = null or no value`, don't know why this happen, i also set `sessionState mode="InProc"`, which stores session state in memory on the Web server but still session turn to default and no data stored from it, please help, any comment will be appriciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a difference between web application and web API. Web API do not support session if you feel you need to share values between two API calls then you need to figure out some other solution. The one which you are trying won't work for sure...

Comment: so it only holds for the default value, whenever I set the default from HttpContext.Current.Session it always returned a null value? can you give me sir best approach/ sample for that, holding value just like session as client side storage? thanks again sir